# Processing an array of objects and assigning them in groups of 4

Tags: javascript

I am trying to process an array of objects (representing game players) to assign each object a group number based on their current group value.

The catch is that each group should have as close to four players as possible and some players want to be in specific groups which must not be broken (but can be renamed or merged).

Some players have unassigned/null groups (they don't want to play with anyone specific) and others want to play with specific people so they have a custom group value.

```
var players = [
    {name: "A", group: null},
    {name: "B", group: null},
    {name: "C", group: null},
    {name: "D", group: null},
    {name: "E", group: null},
    {name: "cA", group: "custom1"},
    {name: "cB", group: "custom1"},
    {name: "cC", group: "custom2"},
    {name: "cD", group: "custom2"},
    {name: "cE", group: "custom3"},
    {name: "cF", group: "custom3"}];
```

I need a way to resolve this array so that it returns something like this:

```
var resolvedGroup = [
    {name: "A", group: 1},
    {name: "B", group: 1},
    {name: "C", group: 1},
    {name: "D", group: 1},
    {name: "cA", group: "customMerged1"},
    {name: "cB", group: "customMerged1"},
    {name: "cC", group: "customMerged1"},
    {name: "cD", group: "customMerged1"},
    {name: "cE", group: 2},
    {name: "cF", group: 2},
    {name: "E", group: 2}
]
```

You can see that the first four players should get assigned to group 1 and the players who initially had custom groups, get merged into groups of four, if possible - otherwise, they should get some of the "null" group players to form as close to four players in a group as possible. The names of the groups don't matter, only that each player who specified a custom group should be able to stay with the initial group members even if they get merged with another custom group.

Comment: This is highly project specific.  Try to break down the problem into smaller subproblems and then when you realize which subproblem is the one you cant solve, come back and update the question.

Comment: Do you want code or just an algorithm?

Comment: I'm not even sure where to begin. Any algorithmic guidance would be appreciated. I'm fiddling with Garr Godfrey's suggestions now.

Answer (score 1):

This requires several steps and a fair amount of coding. You may have to try various things and come up with the best solution. I would start by:

1) Determine how many groups you will need based on the number of players. Most likely this is Math.ceil(numPlayers/4);

2) Create an array of groups by that size. This might be as simple as an array of the count of players in each group.

3) Sort the player list by group name (use sort and a custom comparison function).

4) Go through sorted list, for each group name, count the number of player in that group, find a group that has room for that many players, and add them all to that group.

5) Go through remaining players, adding each to a group. I would start at the end of the array of groups, and move backward after adding each player, looping back to end of group array when it hits the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Requested groups will fall into one of the following categories:

- Players who did not request a group, and (maybe) groups of size 1 (which can be treated as if they had not requested a group).
- Groups of size 2.
- Groups of size 3.
- Groups of size 4.
- Groups of size 5 or greater: these cannot be accommodated, and you will have to make a policy decision about how to deal with them.  I will ignore them from here on out.

The groups of size 4 can, of course, be left as-is.

The groups of size 2 can be paired off with each other - if there are an odd number of such groups, you would have one group left over at the end.

Groups of size 3 can be paired off with unassigned players.  After this step you will have either some surplus size-3 groups or some surplus unassigned players, but not both.  If you have surplus size-3 groups, you will have to just leave them as-is.

If you have surplus unassigned players (and possibly one surplus size-2 group), you can collect them into groups of 4 relatively easily.

In pseudocode:

1. Count the number of players who requested each group name.  This can be done in linear time by iterating over the `players` list and updating a dictionary/hashtable.
2. Convert the hashtable to an array and sort it by group size.
3. Starting at the end of the array, remove size-4 groups, which do not need to be modified.
4. Continuing backwards through the array, for each size-3 group you find, assign its group name to an unassigned player from the beginning of the array (if one exists) and remove both from the array.
5. If unassigned players are exhausted and there are surplus size-3 groups, remove them (they will have to be left as-is).
6. Continuing backwards through the array, for each pair of size-2 groups you find, assign them the same group name and remove them from the array.
7. You will now have at most one size-2 group and possibly more unassigned players.  Collect them into groups of 4.